# docker invalid format ssh key

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose

Im trying to deploy a django app using docker and Gitlab CI/CD . I have a running instance on aws and also created a postgres database for the same . The deployment script is showing error as follows :

```
 Login Succeeded
 $ mkdir -p ~/.ssh
 $ echo "$PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
 $ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa
 $ chmod 700 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
 $ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
 Agent pid 28
 $ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
 Error loading key "/root/.ssh/id_rsa": invalid format
Running after_script
00:02
Uploading artifacts for failed job
00:01
 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: seems like `"$PRIVATE_KEY"` it's not contain valid key. or you can generate a new one using `ssh-keygen`.

Comment: @Adiii Could you please explain the steps as an answer. Doing this for the first time! to generate the keypair , i have to ssh into the aws server?

Comment: The following link should give you a couple resources to find your way: https://www.google.com/search?q=ssh+generate+key+pair

Comment: `ssh-keygen` all you need to run this command, followed by `chmod 700 ~/.ssh/id_rsa` and then `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`. let me know if these command does not

Comment: in my local machine or after ssh into aws instance? @Adiii

Comment: [ec2-user@ip-******* ~]$  chmod 700 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
[ec2-user@ip-****** ~]$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
[ec2-user@ip-***** ~]$

Comment: worked after adding eval `ssh-agent -s`

Comment: Great, yes on a remote server

Comment: but still wrong format error @Adiii

Comment: do i need to add this key to gitlab? @Adiii

Comment: did you generate key with `ssh-keygen`? remove the old one. and you can place `ida_rsa.pub` on any server which you want to access from this server.

Comment: first i ssh into the aws server using the pem .. I then followed the steps ssh-keygen and added the same. Identity added: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa)
.I then tried to run the deploy script again on Gitlab .Same error until now @Adiii

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213538/discussion-between-adiii-and-mohit-harshan).